# Scope - nested functions

Tags: r

I have some code below. Now I is there a way that I can put my function `GETAPI` last in the code after the `lOriginal <- GETAPI` call?

As I understand it, if GETAPI function has not been evaluated before the `GETAPI()` call, R won't search for it within the document. But why not?

If I put the GETAPI function last in the code I get the error:

> couldn't find GETAPI function

Code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(digest)
library(stringi)
library(jsonlite)
library(plyr)

#'@export
#'

query  <- function(area = "stockholm", type="lägenhet", sincesold = "",  FUN  = "", limit = 500, offset = 0) {

  GETAPI  <- function(area = "stockholm", type="lägenhet", sincesold = "",  FUN  = "", limit = 500, offset = 0) {... }

  #raw data fetch + add new columns
  lOriginal  <- GETAPI(area, type, sincesold, FUN, limit, offset)
  lOriginal  <- lOriginal[order(lOriginal$publish, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = TRUE), ]
  row.names(lOriginal)  <- NULL
  lOriginal$AreaSize <- round_any(lOriginal$livingArea, 10, floor)
  lOriginal$PriceDiff  <- lOriginal$soldPrice - lOriginal$listPrice

  #Reclass
  lOriginal$AreaSize  <- as.factor(lOriginal$AreaSize)
  lOriginal$published  <- as.Date(lOriginal$published)
  lOriginal$soldDate  <- as.Date(lOriginal$soldDate)

  return (lOriginal)
}
```

Comment: There is no way to use a function before it has been defined. R is not a compiled language. Each line is interpreted in the order they appear in the code.

Comment: If you wrote your functions into a package, you could place `GETAPI` at the end as you want.  Otherwise, it has to be defined before you call it (technically, writing them into a package defines them before you call them, but allows you to organize the code in the way you choose, then defines all of the functions at once when the package is loaded).

Comment: @Benjamin From the roxygen2 tag it appears they are writing a package. The problem is that the function is defined locally and there a package can't help.

Comment: Oops.  I missed that detail.  But I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this, because I do it routinely.  Let me test something in one of my packages.  I think I know the solution.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that in the OP. But it is a package. Thing is it worked with putting it last greatly until just recently (today morning), and I can't get what's happened. Have tried to put GETAPI last and rebuild but the same result.

Comment: Another question--are both `query` and `GETAPI` a part of the package you're building?

Comment: GETAPI is meant to be a nested function within query. Only query is to able to be called through the package. But they are both part of the same package.

Comment: Does GETAPI need to be nested inside of query?  If you're writing a package you could just make it an unexported function

Comment: Well I know, but It would make sense for me do have it this way. The strange this and what I don't get it why putting the GETAPI function last suddently didn't work anymore (worked great up until this morning)

Comment: Where exactly did you define `GETAPI` before? At the very end of `query` or after `query`'s body? Maybe you had `GETAPI` already in your environment (for some reason) and this morning you "accidentally" ran `rm(list=ls())`.

Comment: Yes that may be it. But that would say that @Benjamin got it wrong? Should I be able to organize the code as I wish when writing in a package?

Comment: @uncool - yes and no.  If you were putting GETAPI outside of query then you should be able to put it anywhere.  If you didn't have GETAPI defined anywhere and put it at the bottom of query then no you shouldn't be able to access it before it's defined inside of query.  I don't know what you did previously and it's impossible to tell but I hope we've made it clear what is and isn't allowable.  If something worked before that shouldn't have been allowable then it's probably because you didn't have a clean workspace.

Comment: Here's an example of a function `plot.HydeNetwork` (https://github.com/nutterb/HydeNet/blob/master/R/plot.HydeNetwork.R).  I call several functions within the plot method that are defined later on (like `mapEdges`).  The common element is each later function is separated with #' @rdname.  But I'm not sure that's entirely necessary, though I recommend separating functions by `################` just to make it easier to see new functions.